# Standardizing individual subjects' scores to their own performance but the SD is 0

Tags: math, statistics

I am working with memory accuracy data under 2 experimental conditions and 1 quiet control condition. Memory scores on a single trial range from 0 to 7 and each individual subject's performance for each condition is averaged across 3 trials (so each subject has a mean accuracy score for each condition that is calculated as (x+x+x)/3). I need to standardize each subject's average performance on the experimental conditions to the subject's specific performance on the quiet control trials (so that I can make inferences about individual differences and make comparisons across different memory measures for each subject). I planned on accomplishing this by taking each individual subject's average memory score for each experimental condition (will call mean of EC1 and EC2), subtracting their average performance on the quiet control trials (mean of Q), and dividing the difference score by the standard deviation of the subject's quiet trials (i.e., difference in performance between EC1 and Q = (MoEC1 - MoQ)/SDoQ). The problem I am encountering is that sometimes subjects get the same number of items correct on each of the 3 quiet trials, so their standard deviation is 0 and I cannot calculate a standardized score. My initial solution was to pool the SD for each experimental condition and the quiet condition, but some subjects have an SD of 0 for both variables. Would appreciate any and all feedback on a mathematically appropriate way to go about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is maths not an excel issue. Perhaps a maths stack or Cross Validated Stack would be better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.